# is it possible to send buffer of byte[] to screen ?

Tags: image-processing, fullscreen, hardware

I want to know if there is any way to send byte array ( that represent simple image ) to some application and this application will show this image on some screen that connected to current machine ?

I have 2 screen connected to my machine.
On the first screen i want to show the operation application that i wrote. 
And on the other machine i want to show the output of the video that i hold => that mean that the second screen will show running images.

Is there is a way to do it ?
If there is a way so how .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Most operating systems today do not allow direct access to the hardware from user mode programs.  However, they do provide interfaces that can accomplish what you need.
Typical examples are using APIs like: OpenGL/DirectX/SDL

You should choose and use one, depending on your OS and exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Most operating systems support multi monitor display. You app must create two Windows (using whatever native windowing system API available) and you can arrange them (either manually or programmatically according to what you specified). For video output you need to select some video format and use a library (e.g. ffmpeg) to display it.